# Nagios Core to Nagios Core Communication

Tags: nagios

Having 2 linux box with Nagios Core, I understand that one way of communicating them is using the NSCA plugin and install client plugin in one and server plugin in the other.

Maybe there is an easier way like slave/master configuration, without using NSCA plugin.

Can you describe possible ways of achiving this?

Real situation is that we have 1 host that uses GPRS, so it's IP is dynamic so we need to send monitoring information to a static IP Nagios server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> NSCA is an addon that allows you to send passive check results from remote Linux/Unix hosts to the Nagios daemon running on the monitoring server. This is very useful in distributed and redundant/failover monitoring setups.

if your GPRS host, with dynamic ip, is using NCSA to communicate with a statically ip'ed nagios server, then there should be no problem, as the nagios destination ip does not change.

if i misunderstood, and you mean the dynamic GPRS host is the nagios server, you can use NRPE, thereby initiating connection from dynamic host to static one.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear:

- Are you trying to connect multiple nagios servers?
- OR are you trying to connect a client with a dynamic IP address to a nagios server?

I suspect it is the later, in which case NCSA is your best option for passive checks where the client pushes (rather than the server pulling) and should not be too complicated to setup. [This page](http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/passivechecks.html) provides a decent insight into how NCSA works.  If on windows, this [blog post](http://hyper-choi.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/nagios-configuring-passive-check-for.html) has a decent coverage of how to get ncsa working from nsclient++

A more recent possibility is via Nagios Remote Data Sender (NRDS) .. which has an accompanying NRDP protocol. Read more at:

- http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Addons/Components/Nagios-Remote-Data-Sender-(NRDS)/details
- http://assets.nagios.com/downloads/nagiosxi/docs/Passive_Monitoring_with_NRDS.pdf

Comment: Yes, is the second. And this client maybe will also have Nagios Core in order to run check_process plugin